# How to add new Yii webapp arguments?

Tags: yii

Using Yii 1.1.14

For those who have customised the `webapp` (ie, mywebapp) command, have you, or do you know, any way on how to add more parameters to that command?

We already have the `git` param for example, we wish to add some interactive prompts to the user too, for example: setup the `config/main.php` files.

Any clue about this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet of the `run()` function:

```
public function run($args) {
    $vcs = false;

    if (isset($args[1])) {
        if ($args[1] != 'git' && $args[1] != 'hg')
            $this->usageError('Unsupported VCS specified. Currently only git and hg supported.');

        $vcs = $args[1];
    }
// ...
```

Just like you see, `$args[1]` must be always the VCS you use.
By logic you need to change/develop the body of `run()` to be adapted to the new arguments you want.

A probably call would be:

```
webapp ../test git setconfig
```

or

```
webapp ../test git true
```

The third argument will be available as `$args[2]`.